# Createchooser in Oreo, problem when opening file

Tags: java, android

I try to open file after downloading the file in my app.
I already make `provider_paths.xml`
and this is what inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```

And I already put this in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

And this is inside my java code, I put this in `BroadcastReceiver` so it will triggered after my app downloading the file but this code doesn't work.
Please help me what's wrong?

```
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(columnIndex)) {
String uriString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
File mFile = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(Uri.parse(uriString).getPath()));
myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MyActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",mFile);

myIntent.setDataAndType(uri, getMimeType(mFile.getAbsolutePath()));

PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(myIntent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

if (isIntentSafe) {
    //choose app to open
    Intent j = Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Choose an application to open with:");
    //startActivity(j);
    //if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    j.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(j);
    //}
}else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No app can't handle",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved..
may be this will help other person who search how to createchooser and intent file to other application in android nougat or above

my code is work just fine..
with only adding
this flag in the right intent;so that's the answer for me

```
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

just look in my code again "myIntent" need the flag